# Linear singly-celled two-layer ANN with produces constant predictions

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, linear-regression, least-squares

Say that we want to fit a straight line in the plane through the origin and the point (1, 2). We can view this as linear regression with a sample of size 1 and no intercept. This, on the other hand, can be represented as a rather trivial neural network with no hidden layers and no activation. In Keras, this would look as follows:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), use_bias=False,
                       kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.Zeros()),
])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=.1))
```

Running

```
model.fit([[1]], [[2]], epochs=50)
```

we get our desired result. Namely, `model.predict([[1]])` produces a number close to 2.

Now, include a second layer in the model:

```
model2 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), use_bias=False,
                       kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.Zeros()),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=False,
                       kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.Zeros())
])

model2.compile(loss='mse',
               optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=.1))
```

This time around, no matter what we throw after `model2.fit`, we'll find that `model2.predict` is constantly equal to zero. Moreover, this happens regardless of which one of Keras' gradient descent algorithms is used.

This is surprising since the two models are equivalent in the sense that the parameter of the first model can be realized as the product of the two parameters in the second one. That is, we are fitting a straight line *y* = *abx* by trying to find values of *a* and *b*. Taking, for instance, *a* = 2 and *b* = 1 would produce a perfect fit.

So, what's the difference?

Comment: Are you initializing all weights to zero? That is generally a very bad idea. Usually small random values are used.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a rather unfortunate side effect of the chosen initial values. It is easy to see that for the given sample, the gradient of the mean squared error optimization objective is

(*a*, *b*) ↦ 2(*b*(*ab* − 2), *a*(*ab* − 2))

which happens to equal zero when (*a*, *b*) = (0, 0). Choosing any other initial values for the parameters, and everything goes through as expected. In particular, using

```
kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(.1)
```

in both layers would produce the desired result.

The same issue does not occur in the one-layer case since here the gradient is

*a* ↦ 2(*a* − 2)

which is zero only when *a* = 2.